# breeze not detecting changes

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze

using durandal/require/breeze/knockout

When I make a change to a value in the text box in the table. breeze is not detecting a change.  manager.hasChanges() always returns false.  Why is breeze not finding that change?

Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public object Lookups()
    {
        var categories =  _contextProvider.Context.KMS_Categories;
        var tags = _contextProvider.Context.KMS_Tag;
        return new { categories, tags };
    }
```

getting Data

```
    var manager = configureBreezeManager(),
    EntityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery;

    return EntityQuery.from('Lookups')
    .using(manager).execute()
    .fail(queryFailed);
```

save changes function

```
   var saveChanges = function () {
    return manager.saveChanges()
    .then(saveSucceded)
    .fail(saveFailed)

    function saveSucceded(saveResult) {
        log('Saved data successfully', saveResult, true);
    }

    function saveFailed(error) {
        var msg = 'Save failed: ' + error.message;
        logError(msg, error);
        error.message = msg;
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Table displaying data and where being changed

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tags</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: adminTags">
                <tr>
                <td ><input class="form-control" data-bind="value: $data.Tag()" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your binding is incorect, you need to write `$data.Tag`

```
<input class="form-control" data-bind="value: $data.Tag" />
```

With writing `$data.Tag()` you are not binding to your observable property itself but you are binding directly to its underlying value which makes your binding effectively **one-way** only.

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UR85s/).

Comment: Thanks that worked.  Any idea why it won't pickup an addition to the ko.observablearray?

        var t = { TagID: adminTags().length + 1, Tag: newTag() };
        adminTags.push(t);

Comment: If your `adminTags` is an observable array then `adminTags.push(t);` should work fine... so your problem is somewhere else

Comment: it adds it to the array just fine, but that save changes isn't picking up the change in breeze;

Comment: You can't push directly into a Breeze navigation property.  Breeze relies on foreign keys to establish relationships so you need to do something like tag().adminId(admin.id());  Where you are setting the navigation property (foreign key) equal to the admin's id, or you could pass the admin directly into the admin property of the tag or w/e.  Consider thoroughly reading the docs

Comment: What section would I focus on?  say I have a list of tags ko array is adminTags. Entity name KMS_Tag consists of a TagID and Tag.